# cakePHP3 テーブルクラスのインスタンスからSQLクエリログを取得する方法

Tags: cakephp

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm.html

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm/database-basics.html#database-query-logging

上記を参考にして、SQLクエリのログを出力しようとしましたが、出力されませんでした。

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

// クエリログを有効
$conn->logQueries(true);

$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');

$query = $articles->find();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
}

// クエリログを停止
$conn->logQueries(false);
```

コネクションについてはTableクラスの
https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_getConnection
も使ってみましたが、同様に出力されませんでした。

他のエラーログなどは出力されています。

正しいやり方を教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config/bootstrap.phpにログ出力の設定はありますか

```
Log::config('queries', [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'file' => 'queries.log',
    'scopes' => ['queriesLog']
]);
```

また、Debugkitが有効になっていると出力されないようです。プラグインを一時的に無効にするか。app.phpのdebug=falseにするなどしてみてください。